# Windows Explorer Context menu opening already running Delphi app

Tags: delphi, contextmenu

If I right click on several files and choose windows context menu, how to send the selected name of files to my program. My program has already running and I dont want my program to be executed again because my program use mutex and uac.

I am using delphi, if you have clues, reference or sample code, really appreciate.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991255/explorer-integration-in-the-context-menu-but-using-the-already-running-instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using launcher app like [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310154/context-menu-delphi/2310169#2310169) suggests you could use DDE to contact already running applications. Another option is writing your own shell extension. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991255/explorer-integration-in-the-context-menu-but-using-the-already-running-instance).

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper app that starts the program if necessary, then sends the filenames to be processed via a mailslot.